# Is it possible to deterministically trace how port 80 is forwarded and where the configuration is on a given system?

Tags: node.js, apache, portforwarding, netstat, lsof

Is there a way to determine or trace how a port forwarding configuration is set up on a system running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, on which there is a NodeJS service running and somehow accepting connections via port 80, although the service itself is running on port 8080, given that it's clear that port 80 connections are being handled by Apache (see details below)?

I have attempted to `lsof -i :80` on the system, and according to `lsof`, there's no process running on port 80. Interestingly, though:

```
ubuntu@ip-***-**-**-***:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      10197/apache2
```

I have dug into the apache configuration, after determining that it is located at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and have not been able to find any `VirtualHost` records, `ProxyPass`, or anything of the sort.

I have also checked `iptables -L` just in case.

Would `httpry` or something like it help figure out the port forwarding configuration and what running processes are responsible for the port forwarding?

Comment: `iptables -L` wouldn't answer the question; you'd want to look at the `nat` table (`iptables -t nat -L`).  Typically Apache reads more than just `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, also, so there may be additional Apache config files under `/etc/apache2` that you should check.

Comment: This is perfect and it worked splendidly. Please change this into an answer, rather than a comment, and I will accept it.

Comment: Answer-ified.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`iptables -L` wouldn't answer the question (this lists the iptables *filter* table); you'd want to look at the *nat* table by running `iptables -t nat -L` (or `iptables -t nat -S`, which produces output in the format of `iptables-save` which I find much easier to read).

Typically Apache reads more than just `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, also, so there may be additional Apache config files under `/etc/apache2` that you should check.